# Abusive cross-posting

Tags: support, status-completed, abuse

This kinda speaks for itself.

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/is-there-a-program-or-app-that-can-sort-items-using-manual-choices-and-deductive
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414376/is-there-a-program-or-app-that-can-sort-items-using-manual-choices-and-deductive
- https://superuser.com/questions/261668/is-there-a-program-or-app-that-can-sort-items-using-manual-choices-and-deductive
- [Is there a program or app that will let you sort items using manual choices and deductive logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28752/is-there-a-program-or-app-that-will-let-you-sort-items-using-manual-choices-and-d)
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5615/is-there-a-program-app-algorithm-that-can-sort-items-using-manual-choices-and
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61347/is-there-a-program-or-app-that-can-sort-items-using-manual-choices-and-deductive
- http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/22171/is-there-a-program-or-app-that-can-sort-items-using-manual-choices-and-deductive
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7372/is-there-a-program-or-app-that-can-sort-items-using-manual-choices-and-deductive

Only found because the perpetrator associated his accounts.

Comment: We should give him the benefit of the doubt and assume it was a misunderstanding of how the system works in my opinion.

Comment: It would be possible to have a tool that checked for cross-posting...

Comment: @Tom: IMHO, he should have known something was wrong when he typed (copy/pasted?) his question for the eighth time.

Answer (score 6):

This might be an isolated incident right now, but I worry it may grow worse in the future. Maybe a close-as-duplicate-on-another-site option? Then the duplicate could live on as a reference to the canonical version (provided it has some value).